# Reassigning a var parameter on Scala's constructor

Tags: scala, parameters, constructor

```
object ReassignTest extends App {
  class X(var i : Int)

  def x = new X(10)
  x.i = 20  // this line compiles

  println(x.i)  // this prints out 10 instead of 20, why?
}
```

So how would I created a setter for parameter `i`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You defined `x` to be a method which returns a new `X` everytime you 'call' it.

```
def x = new X(10) //define a function 'x' which returns a new 'X'
x.i = 20  //create a new X and set i to 20

println(x.i) //create a new X and print the value of i (10)
```

Define `x` to be a value instead, and the behavior will be as you expect

```
val x = new X(10) //define a value 'x' which is equal to a new 'X'
x.i = 20  //set 'i' to be to 20 on the value 'x' defined above 

println(x.i) //print the current value of the variable i defined on the value 'x'
```

Comment: `def` does not declare a function, it declares a method which possibly can return a function.

Comment: Antoras, while technically correct, don't overemphasize the difference between methods and functions. Thanks to Scala's unifying approach, the difference blurs.

Comment: @Antoras Technically (as in, by the spec), `def` declares a function, which can possibly return an anonymous function. But I entirely agree with the spirit of your comment.